# How to list folders and files under c drive in windows server using Ansible

Tags: windows, ansible, ansible-template

I want to list all the folders and files in C drive for windows server using ansible.
Conditions:

1. display the files and folder above 1gb
2. exclude Windows, Users folder
3. throw an error if c drive has more than 20 files

I have tried using the below task but not working.

```
- name: finding files
  win_find:
    paths: 'c:\'
    size: 1g
    file_type: directory
    recurse: no
    excludes: "{{ item }}"
  loop:
    - Windows
    - Users
  register: folder_info
- debug: var=folder_info
```

OUTPUT:
 [WARNING]: win_find failed to check some files, these files were ignored and will not be part of the result output

Can anyone help me out with this use case?

Comment: Which version of ansible do you have?

Comment: @user2700022 I am using 2.9.2

Comment: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/58463 there is an issue, but your version should have the fix for it.

Comment: @user2700022 but not working. even the arguments like size & exclude are working for files but not for folders. For eg: if I try to filter the files using size argument it works fine when I try the same to filter folder it fails..